# Calling an R-Script from NodeRed

Tags: r, api, node-red

I have a question regarding Node-Red and R.
I have simple flow in NodeRed:

[image: NodeRed Flow]

in the 3rd node I try to call a simple R-Script via a get-Request.

[image: get request]

The URL I got by using Plumber and creating an API for the script.
[image: rscriptplumber]

when I run the script in RStudio it works just fine, and I get the following result:

[image: api]

this is what I expect.
When I call the function via NodeRed, unfortunately, I get the code 200 as well, butfollowed by this error:

[image: error]

I am out of ideas what is causing this error, does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong here?
Best regards and thank you

Comment: The error implies you need to supply some credentials to authenticate with R Studio.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. I am logged in to RStudio with the same User I'm creating the NodeRed Flow. Is there some way to call a R-Script without being dependant on RStudio? 

It may be a naive question, sorry for that. I'm fairly new with R.

Comment: But R has no way to associate that user to the request coming from Node-RED, I expect you either need to pass a set of HTTP Basic Auth credentials or a cookie in the headers. Does the curl command shown in RStudio work?

Comment: That makes sense, yes. 
the curl command does work without problems.
What would you recommend is the more managable route for a beginner - the HTTP Basic Auth approach or a cookie?

Comment: Both a simple from a Node-RED point of view, but no idea what R might actually need/want.